# google maps api - customizing maps with local database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am  new to google maps and now I have a requirement to make use of it to provide a presentation to client. I have never worked on maps api or used the developer kit, so hopefully I make sense in what I am asking here.

**Requirement:**  I have generated unique code more like UK POST CODE for each of my distribution center.  I have identified LatLng for each of them and created a database.

We use UK Postcode for navigation, location and etc. This works completely on the database of address provided by royal mail to google.  if I have my own database with a set of custom postcode, will i be able to work on maps using my database

I want to first mark these distribution center on the map and give a demo like distance, navigation between two distribution center working completely offline. All distribution center are within a very small geographical radius as this is just a demo.

So, is it possible to achieve this or any alternative will be very helpful. If this is a duplicate question could you point me to relevant link.

Thanks in advance
/SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have my own database with a set of custom postcode, will i be able to work on maps using my database

Of course you can, Google Maps would be useless if you couldn't work with your own markers, or if you can't add / remove / update / delete them in DB. Please read the [well-documented doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to learn how to deal with it.

> I want to first mark these distribution center on the map and give a demo like distance, navigation between two distribution center working completely offline

You will have to use [DistanceMatrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) to calculate distance between two or more points. But you **NEED** an Internet connexion because you'll send your information to Google and it will send you back the expected result, so you need to be online - no other way.

Comment: Once I add the markers for two location on the map from the database example: RT4 7YU(with latlang) & ZTQ 888(with latlang) does google save this somewhere? can i do a search with the "RT4 7YU" and maps locates the markers which I had previously added?? or am i asking too much?

Answer (score 0):

Completely offline? I would say: no chance. Beside that you would violate Googles [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

Comment: my basic requirement is to give a demo, assumed working with my own database is offline. So, how do I start with my requirement?